# (Low End) Soundbar for PC Monitor

Tags: audio

Background **(may be skipped)**:

I'm owning a desktop computer with a high-end (based on 2010) gaming monitor.
Of course, this monitor doesn't feature speakers.
This didn't bother me until now, but I'm now primarily using my (external) soundcard + headset on my custom docking station (i.e. two USB-Hubs) for my laptop and don't want to re-plug all this whenever I'm at the desktop.
Besides that there are other people using the desktop that occasionally need sound.

---

I'm looking for a soundbar to put below my monitor (much you'd do with a TV).

The mandatory requirements are:

- Really low price (30€ or less preferably)
- Relatively compact size (must not be larger than 57 x 18 cm (W x D))
- Sound can be supplied from the PC (USB or 3.5mm audio jack)
- Sound should be understandable (i.e. you can understand what people are talking in a show)
- The soundbar must be only a single device (i.e. no additional bass)

Optional requirements:

- The PSU (of the soundbar) should be internal
- Good sound quality
- High volume capacity
- You should be able to place the monitor on-top of the soundbar

Answer (score 1):

If found this soundbar on Amazon - The [5ive® Bluetooth Soundbar](http://amzn.to/1URI5rY)

[image]

It's only 38cm, it has all USB, 3.5mm audio jack and bluetooth.  It has it's own power supply and is priced around $40 USD or $35 €

I think this should fit the bill quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm proposing is a hack, involving two-sided scotch tape and splicing wires: DELL AS501 or AX510. They can be bough for as little as 5€ used or 10€ new. They're simple, one-piece analog devices with 3.5mm jack audio input and 5.5mm barrel plug 12V input.

Power supply can be a slight problem without compatible Dell monitor, but it's still relatively simple to either match a 12V/1A power supply (just watch the polarity) or to splice the cable and power it directly from some 12V source you already have (like your desktop PSU).

Comment: Fair warning: I posted a [meta question](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/433/57) about this type of answer. You may wish to weight in.

Comment: @Andy Thanks. Finding a suitable power brick is hardly a true DIY. As for the scotch tape - I think that's unavoidable, given there is no soundbar dedicated to OP's monitor.